# Video chat pro ActiveX public ip

Tags: c#, api, ip, chat, video-conferencing

I used video chat pro ActiveX [from this site][1] . 
I did like the same in [tutorial video][2] .
With local ip adress (192.x.x.x) it's work. but when i put public ip adress, don't work

```
 axVideoChatReceiver1.ReceiveAudioStream = true;
 axVideoChatReceiver1.ReceiveVideoStream = true;
 axVideoChatReceiver1.Listen(193.x.x.x, 1234);
```

What is wrong here?
Thanks in advance
[1]: http://www.viscomsoft.com/products/videochatpro/index.html
[2]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eX_UxxlwEY

Comment: Does your computer really have a network interface with that IP? Are you sure you don't actually want to run the server on your homenetwork-local IP adress, then configure the router to do some port-forwarding sothat your machine can be reached from your public IP?

Comment: I seen axVideoChatServer from this api. I thinks I must use that. I don't know how to use. I seen this video but I don't know how connect sender object with server object and send stream to a another Ip. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eX_UxxlwEY

Comment: I understand less and less. You said things stopped working when you put your public IP instead of your home-local IP. When you are in a network (and NOT the router) with IP let's say `192.168.0.195` with public IP `68.12.34.56`, then you can't `Listen()` on your public IP adress. You have to listen on your local IP and use your Router (at like `192.168.0.1`) to  port-forward every connection to your local `.195` PC, that's what I was talking about. Connecting sender and server objects to another IP is a completly different matter.

Answer (score 0):

Video Chat pro is best working for video conference
But If you use on internet, you should do NAT port forward of PC server
(ex: NAT port: 1234 UDP)
When you connect to external IP of server PC
use canyouseeme for know external IP